# Excel Vlookup Where Column to Search is identified in Preceding column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to write a formula such that the Table_Array of a vLookup is based on a value from another column.  Basically, I want the Vlookup to search on another sheet in a certain column.  The column that should be searched will vary but is identified in the cell to the left of the formula.

For example, here is what I want my formula to look like when the value in the preceding column is 138:

```
=IF(RC[-1] <> "",IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC14,'Marital Status by Country'!C**138**,1,FALSE)=RC14,"GOOD","ERROR"),"ERROR"),"GOOD")
```

---

However, I do not want to hardcode **138**.  I want the formula to look in the cell directly to the left (RC[-1]) and insert whatever value is there.  I have not been able to figure out the syntax to make this happen.  It always evaluates to an error when I try things like this:

```
=IF(RC[-1] <> "",IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC14,'Marital Status by Country'!C **& RC[-1]**,1,FALSE)=RC14,"GOOD","ERROR"),"ERROR"),"GOOD")
```

---

Spreadsheet Visual

[image: Spreadsheet Visual]

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: You can use either the `INDEX` or `CHOOSECOLS` functions. You should hard-code a range rather than using a whole column reference. For example, in a range that has a maximum number of rows of 1000, something like `=INDEX(R1:R1000,,RC[-1])`  or if you have **365**: `=CHOOSECOLS(R1:R1000,RC[-1])`